# Finding occurrences of a sub-string in a large file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, search

I have a **log file** where each line is of the following format:
**date   ipaddr   url   status**

```
2017-03-02  13:02:43  123.123.123.123  /index.html 200
2017-03-02  13:02:46  123.123.123.124  /index.html 200
2017-03-02  13:02:47  123.123.123.125  /about1.html 404
2017-03-02  13:02:49  123.123.123.123  /about.html 200
```

The log file has 1 million lines with up to 1 million unique IP addresses.

And I have a **query file** which is a list of IP addresses with one IP address per line.

```
123.123.123.123
123.123.123.124
123.123.123.125
```

I want to parse the files and for every IP in the query file and print 1 if it was seen in the log file, otherwise 0.

What would be the fastest way to search the log file. Would pickling be helpful in this?

Comment: How big is the query file? Are the first three fields guaranteed to be of the same length (e.g., no errant spaces)? I'm not sure how pickling is applicable here, what did you have in mind?

Comment: Make a set of the _query_ addresses; iterate through each line in the log file , extract the address from the line; use ```in``` to check if the line address is in the query set; collect the results of the checks.

Comment: At fastest would be to useing `miltiprocessing` and if `query file` is big a BTree or `numpy.array` DataFrame for this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, it will stop searching once all are found:

```
with open('query.txt', 'r') as q:
    query = {line.strip(): 0 for line in q.readlines()}
with open('log.txt', 'r') as l:
    for line in l:
        check = line.split()[2]
        if check in query:
            query[check] = 1
        if sum(query.values()) == len(query):
            break
for k, v in query.items():
    print k, v
```